# How do you set a filter view in Google Sheet that filters the last 24 hours of data?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data logging program that creates rows of data every 10 minutes. This is displayed in a chart.
The first column is a timestamp, with date and time. I want to only display the last 24 hours of data in my chart, so thought that a filter view would do the trick. I selected the column and chose "Filter by condition" and "Greater than or equal to", with "Now() -1" as the value. I tried various other combinations but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct: use the filter view

> Filter by condition -> Greater than or equal to -> `=now()-1`

A common mistake is to omit `=`, possibly this is the reason it didn't work for you.

A similar-sounding "date is after" condition would not be appropriate here, as it ignores the time part of the date.